# build a table with ng-repeat based on lists, ordered by columns in AngularJS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, list, html-table

I'd like to build a table with `ng-repeat`. But in my JavaScript code, instead of having a list with keys and values, I have 3 lists in one bigger list like this:

```js
tableau = [{
    'ws': wslist
  },
  {
    'days': dayslist
  },
  {
    'tnq': tnqlist
  },
]
```

What's in the lists? `wslist`, `dayslist`, and `tnqlist` fill up themselves with dynamic *datas in realtime* that refresh themselves very frequently.

I'd like to know if I can display this data / these lists, in a table with `ng-repeat` ( and **not** with a static key/value pair dataset as we usually see like `var table = [{perons : Arnold, Katty}, {Age : 24, 25}]` and put them *in row* in a table with ng repeat).

I tried this :

```html
<table cellpadding="20" rules="GROUPS" frame="BOX">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="xl154" style="width: 100px">
        Day 1something like {{day.tableau}}
      </th>
      <th class="xl154" style="width: 100px">day 2</th>
      <th class="xl154" style="width: 100px">day 3</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in  ctrl.tableau">
      <td class="xl153">{{item.ws}}</td>
      <td class="xl153">{{item.tnq}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I got this :

[image: table I have]

All the values of `wslist` are in one and same cell and in row. They should be separated and each on in its cell in column. My table should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsYx2.png), [more specifically like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00EAO.png) (on the pic, the values of `tnq%` are meant to be read **vertically** in column for day 1 for example, then for day 2 also vertically etc...)

To give you an idea of the length and the nature of the list, you have in the first pic: in red, [this is the wslist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXX2q.png)  and in [the second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vYA0.png): in blue you have the `tnqlist` and in red the `dayslist`.

Do you know if it is possible to do it with `ng-repeat` and if so, how can I do to **order each element of the list in a cell in column** for the `wslist` and the `tnqlist` (so 2 separated columns) ? or ifit is not possible is there **any other way** I can build a table **as in the picture "table I should have"** with my list of dynamic lists?

**Thank you** very much for all answers that may help

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsYx2.png), but if it's just iterating over those inner arrays inside the outer `ng-repeat`, you can just have nested `ng-repeat`s, and even nested tables if you need. Can you provide a more specific mock up of what you want the display to look like?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I don't really know how I'm supposed to iterate or to nest ng-repeat or tables, could you give me an example please? The thing is that each element of one list should have its own cell and be disposed in collumn. Also I've just added a more specific mock of the display I'd like, as you asked. Thank you very much

Comment: So I think what I'm struggling to understand is how this data structure works, regardless of how it's rendered on screen. To use your updated screenshot as an example, how are you supposed to know that `sbe_global-service-requests-for-selfcare` corresponds to 100% on Day 1, 0 on Day 2, and 152 on Day 3? `wslist` has 768 elements and `tnqlist` has 1245 elements, so it's not like their indexes align. If they did, a object structure could be inferred. I'm not sure how these data are related to one another. Could you clarify that for me?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, what you're trying to do is more complex than expected and we don't know the relationship between the data.

Here is a plnkr based on your explanation: https://plnkr.co/edit/REHNDW8CU330yBPY

So, my recommendation would be:

1. For the titles, you can iterate over the list of days. Something like:

```html
<head>
  <tr>
    <th>Web Service </th>
    <th style="width: 100px" ng-repeat="day in daysList">
      {{day}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

2. Then, for each service, you will have to iterate writing the name, but also looking for the value of each day. Something like this:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="ws in wsList">
  <td class="xl153">{{ws}}</td>
  <td style="width: 100px" ng-repeat="day in daysList">
    {{getValue(ws, $parent.$index, day, $index)}}. 
  </td>      
</tr>
```

Where `getValue` is a custom function based on your needs to get the information.